# Application of Laplace Transform to Circuits containing Diodes, etc

Tags: diodes, laplace-transform

Can I use the transform methods and treat the "approximated" diode, say Silicon, as a 0.7 Volts power source and convert it into the S - domain, 0.7/s ?

Are there any advance methods for treating circuits containing diodes?

Comment: For what purpose? Laplace transform is not transforming a "circuit" it is transforming a certain transfer function in time domain. So which function do you want to transform?

Comment: For obtaining response in circuits containing R L and C. The usual methods are finding the q point, etc and solve the system numerically.

Comment: I also wish to solve for transfer functions for complex circuits containing a lot of diode and RLC elements.

Comment: Diode is a non-linear element and has a non-linear transfer function that cannot be analyzed using Laplace transform. If you can "linearize" your circuit around your operation point, then you can try using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot, the Laplace transform only applies to linear differential equations. Therefore, in circuit analysis, you can only apply it to linear elements such as Resistors, capacitors and inductors.

However, you can linearize a diode around an operating point "e", for example

$$ V = V_e + \delta_V \\ $$
$$  I = I_e + \delta_U \\ $$

You will now be able to define a linearized transfer function.

$$ H(s) = \frac{\delta_I}{\delta_V}
 $$

I've used this principle to control in closed-loop the output current of a diode.